# How to obtain the ID of the last listed items?

Tags: postgresql

I want to implement cursor pagination in my server rendered page:

```sql
SELECT id, first_name, last_name 
FROM person 
WHERE id <= 35 
ORDER BY id DESC 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

```
 id | first_name | last_name 
----+------------+-----------
 35 | last       | added
 34 | Carlos     | Luiz
 33 | Ronnie     | Cruz
 32 | Sam        | Harris
 31 | Jeff       | Keller
 30 | Matthew    | Johnson
 29 | Caleb      | Brahm
 28 | Oly        | Sefer
 27 | Vanessa    | McKay
 26 | Mellisa    | Regan
(10 rows)
```

I need to store the value `26` in a variable on the server, that's the next cursor. A link will receive it in the templating engine: http://localhost:8080/people?cursor=26 and so on.

```sql
SELECT id, first_name, last_name 
FROM person 
WHERE id < 26 
ORDER BY id DESC 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

```
id | first_name | last_name 
----+------------+-----------
 25 | Andrew     | Thomas
 24 | Dune       | Rusell
 23 | Lesley     | Parkes
 22 | Samantha   | Fuchs
 21 | Irine      | Bruy
 20 | Elena      | Hardjo
 19 | Maria      | Romano
 18 | Daniel     | Weber
 17 | Peter      | Heintz
 16 | Chelsee    | Robinson
```

How can I obtain that row with ID 26? The limit is 10 rows as you can see above, but I need the ID of the last listed item.
Thank you!

Comment: I would remember that ID in the code that displays the data, rather than trying to do that in SQL - you need to iterate over the rows anyway when you build the page on the server

Comment: Thanks, you're a genius! I didn't think about that.